# How does Prefill enabled true help manage Data Connections

Tags: jboss6.x, jboss-eap-6

I have hosted an application on JBoss EAP 6.2 and have to constantly flush the pool, otherwise the system gets slow and gives the error "Cabinet not found". I wanted to know if I enable **Prefill Enabled**, it will prefill the connection pool with the minimum number of connections, but will this help in auto-flushing the connections?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

prefill:

whether to attempt to prefill the connection pool to the minimum number of connections. NOTE: only supporting pools (OnePool) support this feature. A warning can be found in the logs if the pool does not support this. This feature is available in JBoss 4.0.5 and above.

prefill and allow-multiple-users are mutually exclusive.

You have to constantly flush the pool means:

```
1.The datasource connection pool has not been tuned correctly for the maximum load of the application. Either the pool size needs to be increased, or the blocking timeout extended, or both.
2.The application is leaking connections because it is not closing them and returning them to the pool.
3.Threads with connections to the database are hanging and holding on to the connections.
4. Datasource connection Pool exhaustion.
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this hasn't really answered my question.  I know the definition of prefill connections. My concern was whether it will help in auto-flushing the connections?

Comment: My concern was whether it will help in auto-flushing the connections?  Ans: no

Answer (score 0):

Note that use of `prefill` can cause connection leaks.